# How is it possible to have different kind of letters in latex

Tags: fonts

I wonder how can I have these kind of D's in latex ?

[image]

Comment: The first looks like `\mathfrak{D}` or `\mathcal{D}` (math-mode), the second one looks like a variant of `\DH`/`\DJ`. The exact output depends on your font. Have you seen [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know there exist such a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is available through package `txfonts`. The second one is like `\DJ` (package `fontenc` required). Also a poor's-man approximation can be made:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\otherD{\rlap{\hskip.2ex\rule[.65ex]{1.4ex}{.5pt}}\emph{D}}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{D}$ \emph{\DJ} \otherD{}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: One should note that `\usepackage{txfonts}` changes *all* document fonts.